# Integration tests SQL files difficult to maintain

Tags: sql, testing, tdd, automated-tests, integration-testing

**Our problem:** We have a good set of integration tests (end-to-end) and each of them have a SQL file is executed before the test to prepare the database. Over the time, it's more difficult to maintain these SQL files.

**Example:** If we add a new mandatory column in a table, we have to change all the SQL files (we have for testing) where we have this table and also the seed data we have for it.

It's very time consuming and it will be worse and worse as the number of SQL files grows up. How can we improve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be to reconsider your parameterized queries. If your SQL files execute structurally similar queries many times, you can try to compile the query one time and executing it with different parameters.  In order to achieve better re usability, you can store the (already) existing queries in variables/params/procedures. Here a big advantage will be, that one query change will be propagated through the rest.  You can read more about [Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) here.

Another approach that may be helpful if you want to reuse the *SQL text* of the queries, is defining views (probably) the best way.

If you want to reuse the result of the queries, then you should consider global temporary tables. These temporary tables store data for the duration of session or transaction (whichever you choose). These are really useful in case you need to reuse calculated data many times over, especially if your queries are indeed "ugly" and "horrible" (meaning long running). See [Temporary tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1138) for more information.

If you need to keep the data longer than a session, you can consider materialized views.